# Xamarin Forms localization in iOS native library

Tags: ios, forms, xamarin, localization

I have an iOS library that uses localized string files. When used in a native iOS project in XCode, this library renders the proper text just fine.

However, when imported into a Xamarin Forms project, the library is not able to properly display the localized text. It seems to not find any of the string files at all. The method of localizing a Xamarin Forms project does not seem to be working for this library (ie the plist file, Base folder and other langs). Images referenced by the library work fine though.

Is there a different way for library projects to find localized files than normal Xamarin Forms projects?

Here is the link to the approach for localization in Xamarin.iOS. I realize this is not Xamarin Forms but it's the approach I used.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/localization/

Comment: For clarity, please show a bit more detail re "(plist file, Base folder and other langs)". Or at least point to the doc that describes the approach.

Comment: I added the link to the MS document.

Comment: I think you could try to check if your `lproj` file is placed in the `Resources folder`, and then confirm the Build Action is `Bundle Resource`. And also invoke your iOS method in Xamarin Forms by `DependencyService`.